# How to react to interacton (djs v13)

Tags: discord.js

How do I react (with an emoji) to an interaction message via. discord.js v13? If it's too difficult of a task, I'd rather just come up with an alternative instead of a long complex expression. If you know how, let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: Interactions are not messages, so you can not react with an emoji. You could reply with an emoji, but that's about it.

Comment: The closest thing there is to a reaction with interaction commands is the [MessageButton](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christoph pointed out, interactions are not messages. They're events that are fired at your client, and you're expected to reply to either with a new message, edit the origin message, or soon a modal.

If you want to reply to a command then react on your reply, you can do it like so:

```js
// replied is an instance of CommandInteraction
const replied = await interaction.reply("My message")
await replied.react("")
```

But you cannot react to the actual command, as the command isn't a message, it's an event. That just replied to the command normally with a message, then reacts on the bot's message.

If you want to react on a message when a button in that message is clicked, you can do that like so:

```js
// interaction is an instance of MessageComponentInteraction
await interaction.deferUpdate() // this stops it erroring, as we don't actually reply to the button
await interaction.message.react("")
```

Which will defer the button (tells discord we don't want to reply, so we don't get "Interaction failed"), then react on the message which the button is a part of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for discord.js v14:

```
const replied = await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embed],
        fetchReply: true,
})
await replied.react("✅")
await replied.react("❌")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add reactions to a interaction message.

```js
await interaction.reply({content:'content', fetchReply:true}).then((msg) => {
    msg.react('✖️')
    msg.react('⭕')
})
```

This might sometimes result in the reactions not showing up in order. To fix this you can add the other reaction after the first has been added:

```js
await interaction.reply({content:'content', fetchReply:true}).then((msg) => {
    msg.react('✖️').then(()=>{
        msg.react('⭕')
    })
})
```